# Generating days in a specific range

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server

I have a query in MSSQL, where I get a summary by days from a range in a table, and this is in union with other queries. This query is used to generate days in a specific range, then add the registry per day, and exclude the registry that are equal to others (in this case, count the rows that tipo is 1, and tipo = 0, and if both are equal, exclude this), and then do a union with a single query.

Is there any way to improve this query?

```
USE [C:\PROGRAMDATA\REGISFING\REGISFING.MDF];
/* Borre las tablas temporales si existen. */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Period') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Period;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Registro') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Registro;

DECLARE @FInicio date = '29/02/2016';
DECLARE @FFinaliza date = '04/04/2016';
/* Los siguientes son para utilizar los listados en los filtros */
DECLARE @Cedula table(Ced int);
INSERT @Cedula(Ced) VALUES (1073237901), (1032456940), (1070622582), (45504769);
DECLARE @Puntos table(Punto int);
INSERT @Puntos(Punto) VALUES (0), (43), (99);
/* Importante al pasar al .Net se debe modificar y adjuntar según las elecciones en los controles */

WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(date,Inicio,101) AS StartTime,
            DATEDIFF(dd, Inicio, Finaliza) AS diff, cedula
        FROM Asignaciones
            /* Aquí colocar el codigo para las cedulas específicas */
                WHERE cedula IN (SELECT Ced FROM @Cedula)
UNION ALL 
    SELECT StartTime, diff - 1 AS diff, cedula 
        FROM CTE
            WHERE diff <> 0)

    SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(dd, diff, StartTime) AS Dias, C.cedula
        INTO #Period
        FROM CTE C, Asignaciones A
            WHERE C.cedula = A.cedula
                    /* Filtra entre las fechas especificadas */
                    AND (DATEADD(dd, diff, StartTime) BETWEEN @FInicio AND @FFinaliza)
        GROUP BY StartTime, C.cedula, diff--, R.Fecha
        ORDER BY C.Cedula, Dias

SELECT R.cedula, (CAST(Fecha AS date)) AS Dia, Tipo_Reg, COUNT(CAST(R.Fecha AS date)) AS Cantidad
    INTO #Registro
    FROM Registro R
            /* Filtra entre las fechas especificadas */
        WHERE R.Fecha BETWEEN @FInicio AND @FFinaliza
            /* Filtra entre las cedulas especificadas */
            AND cedula IN (SELECT Ced FROM @Cedula)
            /* Filtra entre las ubicaciones especificadas */
            AND (R.IdUbicacion IN (SELECT Punto FROM @Puntos))

GROUP BY R.cedula, (CAST(R.Fecha AS date)), R.Tipo_Reg

/* Se unen las dos consultas temporales */
SELECT 'XX No timbrados' AS column1,
        CONCAT(p.cedula, ' ', U.Nombre, ' ', U.Apellido) AS column2,
        'Diferencias' AS column3,
        CAST(p.Dias AS datetime) AS column4,
        CONCAT('Entradas: ', CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 0 THEN Cantidad END) IS NULL THEN 'No timbró' ELSE CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 0 THEN Cantidad END) AS varchar) END, 
            ' - Salidas: ', CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 1 THEN Cantidad END) IS NULL THEN 'No timbró' ELSE CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 1 THEN Cantidad END) AS varchar) END) AS column5
    FROM Usuario U, #Period p
        LEFT JOIN #Registro r on r.cedula = p.cedula AND r.Dia = p.Dias
    WHERE U.cedula = P.cedula
    GROUP BY P.cedula, U.Nombre, U.Apellido, CAST(p.Dias AS datetime)
        HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 0 THEN Cantidad END) IS NULL OR SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 1 THEN Cantidad END) IS NULL
                OR SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 0 THEN Cantidad END) <> SUM(CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 1 THEN Cantidad END)

    UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(P.IdUbicacion, ' ', P.nombre) AS column1,
        CONCAT(U.cedula, ' ', U.Nombre, ' ', U.Apellido) AS column2,
        (CASE WHEN R.Tipo_Reg = 1 THEN 'Entrada' ELSE 'Salida' END) AS column3,
        N.Fecha AS column4,
        N.Observacion AS column5
    FROM Novedades N, Usuario U, Registro R, Ubicacion P
        WHERE (U.cedula = N.cedula
            AND R.cedula = N.cedula
            AND R.Fecha = N.Fecha
            AND R.IdUbicacion = P.IdUbicacion)
            AND R.Fecha BETWEEN @FInicio AND @FFinaliza

ORDER BY column1, column2, column4
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.